# ie10 select box display

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-10

First post so apologies if this has been asked before. I have not been able to find a solution.

I know with the move to IE10, the options are displayed above and below the currently selected option. I can live with that. However, the options are surrounded by a thick (2px) solid black line. I have tried to manipulate the css with

```
select:focus {
  border: 1px solid #c3c3c3;
}
```

yet that doesn't seem to have any effect.

Any advice would be gratefully received.

Jon

Comment: Can you show us the rest of the code? -  maybe in a jsfiddle

Comment: Have you tried using `outline` rather than `border`? (and yes, a jsfiddle to demonstrate what you mean would be helpful)

Answer (score 0):

maybe with a mouse hover instead of a focus?
I don't really understand what you mean by selected option

Answer (score 0):

IE10 has a few pseudo elements to deal with form styling, such as styling the disclosure arrow on selects with ::-ms-expand [0]. However, there does not seem to be a way, that I can find documented, that allows the pop-up part of the select control to be styled.

[0] http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh767361.aspx

Comment: i find myself in the same situation...@davidstorey is there a proper term for it @ least? google fu will always fail looking for the wrong term(s)...i want to say this is dom shadow, but my first thought after that without referencing a thing is that this is what dom shadow will do/be/is, however since its not in use in my situation, it is not. sorry for the ramblings.